# Change image on hover with transition using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using JavaScript  to change image on hover. However, the *transition* between the 2 images does not work as expected using this css and code

```js
function changeImageOnHoverOver() {
  var changeImg = document.getElementById('change-img');
  changeImg.setAttribute("src", "https://demotheme.site/prestashop/at_kola_demo/51-large_default/mug-the-best-is-yet-to-come.jpg");
}

function changeImageOnHoverOut() {
  var changeImg = document.getElementById('change-img');
  changeImg.setAttribute("src", "https://demotheme.site/prestashop/at_kola_demo/36-home_default/the-best-is-yet-to-come-framed-poster.jpg");
}
```

```css
a img {
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <img src="https://demotheme.site/prestashop/at_kola_demo/36-home_default/the-best-is-yet-to-come-framed-poster.jpg" onmouseover="changeImageOnHoverOver()" onmouseout="changeImageOnHoverOut()" alt="" id="change-img" width="300">
</a>
```

Comment: [The list of animatable properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) (src is not one of them)

Answer (score 3):

**[CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) only work for [properties that can be expressed as numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).** Given the current value, the final value, and the time needed to get from one to the other, the CSS rendering engine is capable determining how to "transition" from one property value to another. An image `src` is not a value that can be expressed as a number and so your code doesn't do anything.

Instead, use a property like [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) to create a cross-fade effect. Opacity takes a value from 0 to 1, so it works with transitions.

Also, if you want the effect to happen on mouse over and mouse out, no JavaScript is needed, just use the CSS [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) to apply a style only when the element is being moused over. When it's not, the style is removed.

```css
.container img {
  height:200px;
  /* Positioning the images absolute allows them to stack on top of each other */
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

/* Change the opacity when the top image is hovered, which
   will reveal the bottom image */
.container img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="bottom" 
    src="https://demotheme.site/prestashop/at_kola_demo/36-home_default/the-best-is-yet-to-come-framed-poster.jpg">
  <img class="top" 
   src="https://demotheme.site/prestashop/at_kola_demo/51-large_default/mug-the-best-is-yet-to-come.jpg">
</div>
```